# I am trying to access a gitlab yaml from another project within same group in my main project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Code:

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'testing-parent-pipeline/Testing-child-push'

    file: 'script/test.yml'
```

I am getting this error

Project `testing-parent-pipeline/Testing-child-push` not found or access denied! Make sure any includes in the pipeline configuration are correctly defined.

Comment: I can suggest based on your data.
Please check:
1. Is `testing-parent-pipeline` a root gitlab group (without any more child) ?

2. Is `Testing-child-push` a name or link of gitlab project?

3. Is `Testing-child-push` not a private project, that couldn't be seen by main?

4. Is `Testing-child-push` have 'script/test.yml' in **default** branch?

Answer (score 6):

Please try to check what is the absolute path of your project. To make sure the path is correct please check under

```
settings -> general -> advanced
```

When you expand advanced there is a section called `change path` that is where you will see the real path. Use that as the correct path like this

```
include:
  - project: 'testing-parent-pipeline/Testing-child-push'
    ref: master
    file: 
      -'script/test.yml'
```

Comment: I was missing `ref: main` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`